# Purging Tables in SQL SERVER : deleting time

Tags: sql, sql-server, data-cleaning

i'm in charge of an OLAP database where i noticed that some cleaning would do some benefits.
my  first analysis comes across 500Millions rows to be deleted in approximatively 50 tables . and this represents in general 70% of each table.

i've come across some solution where i need to use a tmp table, drop the original one then bring it again ... but i have too many dependencies and i don't want to take the risk going through that path.

so i went for another solution : 
deleting little by little so there is no table locks.

this is a code i've found here in stack overflow that i've tried to improve 
deleting 4000 by 4000 rows.

```
set statistics time off

DECLARE @BATCHSIZE INT, @WAITFORVAL VARCHAR(8), @ITERATION INT, @TOTALROWS 
INT, @MAXRUNTIME VARCHAR(8), @BSTOPATMAXTIME BIT, @MSG VARCHAR(500)
SET DEADLOCK_PRIORITY LOW;
SET @BATCHSIZE = 4000
SET @WAITFORVAL = '00:00:10'
SET @MAXRUNTIME = '18:00:00' -- 6 PM
SET @BSTOPATMAXTIME = 1 -- ENFORCE  6 PM STOP TIME
SET @ITERATION = 0 -- LEAVE THIS
SET @TOTALROWS = 0 -- LEAVE THIS


Begin TRY

WHILE @BATCHSIZE>0
    BEGIN

-- IF @BSTOPATMAXTIME = 1, THEN WE'LL STOP THE WHOLE JOB AT A SET TIME...
 IF (CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),GETDATE(),108) >= @MAXRUNTIME AND @BSTOPATMAXTIME=1) OR @ITERATION >2000
    BEGIN
        Return;
    END 


        DELETE top (@BATCHSIZE)
        FROM FacY where IdDimX not in (select IdDimX from  vwX)


SET @BATCHSIZE=@@ROWCOUNT
SET @ITERATION=@ITERATION+1
SET @TOTALROWS=@TOTALROWS+@BATCHSIZE
SET @MSG = 'Iteration: ' + CAST(@ITERATION AS VARCHAR) + ' Total deletes:' + CAST(@TOTALROWS AS VARCHAR)
RAISERROR (@MSG, 0, 1) WITH NOWAIT
--COMMIT TRANSACTION;

 END
end TRY 
BEGIN CATCH
 IF @@ERROR <> 0
   AND @@TRANCOUNT > 0
    BEGIN
        PRINT 'There is an error occured.  The database update failed.';
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
    END;
END CATCH;
```

so this took approx. between 30min and one hour to delete 4Million rows.

instead i trie now to delete 100 000 rows and it did so in 1minutes then i tried 1Millions rows and it did it 5-6minutes.
then i went for more 10million rows and it took 15minutes. ( but logs of 50GB were full at 60% so i think it's the limit)

so now i'm wondering isn't it better if i go deleting by big blocks finally ? since it would take a lot of time.

and what i don't understand is why it takes less time to delete by big blocks?

thanks for your help

Comment: Does your edition of SQL Server allow for partitioning? If so, it would be far better to partition your tables and switch out the partitions you don't need.

Comment: There is a "sweet spot" between too large and too small. Too small and the amount of IO slows things down. Too large and size of the transaction bloats tempdb. I have found that around 100,000 is a pretty reasonable size most of the time. But as with everything can't stress the importance of testing.

Comment: There is no magic number; too many variables. See [this](https://sqlperformance.com/2013/03/io-subsystem/chunk-deletes), [this](https://am2.co/2019/04/the-thrill-of-purging-old-data/), [this](https://am2.co/2019/04/purging-data-with-batched-deletes/), [this](https://am2.co/2019/04/code-to-purge-data-on-creation-date/), and [this](https://michaeljswart.com/2014/09/take-care-when-scripting-batches/).